# How to select info about indexes with specified columns from all databases in the instance using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, query, cursors, metadata, index-maintenance

This query selects all the indexes - its names, fragmentation, and some other parameters from the current database.

```
select
    idx.[name] as [index_name],
    sc.[name] as [schema_name],
    obj.[name] as [table_name],  
    ips.[avg_fragmentation_in_percent] as [fragmentation_percent]
from sys.indexes as idx
inner join sys.objects as obj on idx.object_id = obj.object_id
inner join sys.schemas as sc  on obj.schema_id = sc.schema_id
cross apply sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats( DB_ID(), idx.object_id, idx.index_id, NULL ,'LIMITED') AS ips
where idx.[name] is not NULL 
order by [fragmentation_percent] desc;
```

Now I need to select all the indexes with specified columns from **all databases**. I can use `USE [dbname]` when I execute the statement manually, but I need to put it in a cursor, so I cannot write `USE [dbname]` in a cursor.

How can I substitute the database selection in the `...CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats( DB_ID(), ...` part of my statement?

Help will be much appreciated to show how can I select all database indexes with a single query.

Something like this:

```
declare cr_index cursor
for
exec(@dynamicUSE)
select
    idx.[name] as [index_name],
    sc.[name] as [schema_name],
    obj.[name] as [table_name],  
    ips.[avg_fragmentation_in_percent] as [fragmentation_percent]
from sys.indexes as idx
inner join sys.objects as obj on idx.object_id = obj.object_id
inner join sys.schemas as sc  on obj.schema_id = sc.schema_id
cross apply sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats( DB_ID(), idx.object_id, idx.index_id, NULL ,'LIMITED') AS ips
where idx.[name] is not NULL 
order by [fragmentation_percent] desc;
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you "need to put it in a cursor"? If you get the results, does it matter it `declare cursor` was used? Do you need to do something else with each result that you haven't told us about?

Comment: Yes, I want to write a program to automatically rebuild indexes where its fragmentation > 30. It works fine for one database, but I want to run it for all databases in my instance. I want a query to select all the indexes in the instance(I have 4 databases). The query printed above selects indexes only for current database. When I change the database, it works fine for the other one. But I want to know, is it possible to write the select statement the way that it will select all indexes?

Comment: You could do a job on the server that will do it for you. You can use Olga's maintenance script. https://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: Why are you re-inventing what Ola already provides for you for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do dynamic SQL in a cursor to do it on every database on the server that way :

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
 SELECT @Command = 'USE [' +  @DB_Name + '];  select
   idx.[name] as [index_name],
   sc.[name] as [schema_name],
   obj.[name] as [table_name],  
   ips.[avg_fragmentation_in_percent] as [fragmentation_percent]
from sys.indexes as idx
inner join sys.objects as obj on idx.object_id = obj.object_id
inner join sys.schemas as sc  on obj.schema_id = sc.schema_id
cross apply sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats( DB_ID(), idx.object_id, idx.index_id, NULL ,''LIMITED'') AS ips
where idx.[name] is not NULL 
order by [fragmentation_percent] desc;'
 EXEC sp_executesql @Command

 FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

Comment: Actually I want to select all the index names into cursor

Comment: something like this - declare cr_index cursor
 for
 exec(@dynamicUSE)
 select
  idx.[name] as [index_name],
  sc.[name] as [schema_name],
  obj.[name] as [table_name],  
  ips.[avg_fragmentation_in_percent] as [fragmentation_percent]
 from sys.indexes as idx
 inner join sys.objects as obj on idx.object_id = obj.object_id
 inner join sys.schemas as sc  on obj.schema_id = sc.schema_id
 cross apply sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats( DB_ID(), idx.object_id, idx.index_id, NULL ,'LIMITED') AS ips
 where idx.[name] is not NULL 
 order by [fragmentation_percent] desc;